# Select checkbox list item depending upon character in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string variable as follows

```
string s = "QQQNQQQ";
```

I also have a CheckboxList with the following items

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbWorkPattern" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cbWorkPattern_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Sunday" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Monday" Value="1" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Tuesday" Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Wednesday" Value="3" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Thursday" Value="4" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Friday" Value="5" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Saturday" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I want to select each CheckBox in the CheckBoxList when a character in a string s is equal to "Q". For example, in the given string above, Wednesday should be unselected and the remaining days should be selected. How can I achieve this using c#?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you will always have exactly seven characters, you could iterate through your string and select the items from your `CheckBoxList` that using the indices that contain "Q" :

```
string s = "QQQNQQQ";
// Iterate through your string
for(var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
     // If the current character is 'Q', then select this option
     if(s[i] == 'Q')
     {
          // Find the cooresponding value for this element and select it
          cbWorkPattern.Items.FindByValue(i.ToString()).Selected = true;
     }
}
```

which would yield :

[image]